# Python realtime mousedata with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, pyqtgraph

In my epic struggle to process raw mouse data on my ubuntu (14.04) OS with python, with alot help from here i am stuck again. It seems very hard for me to understand the "easyness" of pyqtgraph. all i want to do is to wrap the code i have now into a nice little gui with a start/pause/stop button, a list widget to show the numbers and a plot to let me see whats happening. I guess the main problem for me is, that i dont quite understand this whole event thing in pyqt.
anyway taking a "easy" example which has the widgets i want, i fail to implement my code(edited more minimalistic):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import threading
import struct
import time
import numpy as np

from PyQt4 import QtGui  # (the example applies equally well to PySide)
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
##
data =[(0,0)]
sum_data = [(0,0)]
file = open("/dev/input/mouse2", "rb") 

def getMouseEvent():
  buf = file.read(3);
  #python 2 & 3 compatibility 
  button = buf[0] if isinstance(buf[0], int) else ord(buf[0])
  x,y = struct.unpack( "bb", buf[1:] );
  print x,y
  return x, y

def mouseCollect():
  while True:        
   data.append(getMouseEvent())
   sum_data.append(tuple(map(sum,zip(sum_data[-1],data[-1]))))
   plot.plot(sum_data[0], clear=True)
   pg.QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
   print sum_data[-1]       

## Always start by initializing Qt (only once per application)
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

## Define a top-level widget to hold everything
w = QtGui.QWidget()

## Create some widgets to be placed inside
btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Start')

listw = QtGui.QListWidget()
plot = pg.PlotWidget()

def start_btn():
  print 'test'
  threading.Thread(target=mouseCollect).start()  

btn1.clicked.connect(start_btn)  

## Create a grid layout to manage the widgets size and position
layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
w.setLayout(layout)    
## Add widgets to the layout in their proper positions
layout.addWidget(btn1, 0, 0)   # button goes in upper-left   
layout.addWidget(plot, 0, 1, 4, 1)      
## Display the widget as a new window
w.show()    
## Start the Qt event loop
app.exec_()
##------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when i press the start button, the window just freezes and nothing happens. my thought was, if i press the button, it connects to the methot state there and it just doing its stuff. okay i have an infinite loop, but at least i thought i should see something. any help is apreciated, also any tips for a good reading about the matter is very welcome.

regards
Edit: inserted a thread as suggested by echocage

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If what you're saying is the button works, and `mouseCollect` is called, then the problem is just in `mouseCollect` - none of the buttons are needed at all in this example. Also, make sure your indentation is correct.

Comment: Edited. I dont know where to cut of more and still  be complete :) Tested it and has the same problem. Thx.

Comment: Ok so I think you problem is that you're running mouseCollect in the same thread. Because you're waiting forever in the loop, when the mouse event handler doesn't return it freezes the GUI. Try running mouseCollect in a new thread to avoid this, though I can't tell you how PyQT handles multithreaded calls. 

You can do that by importing Thread from the threading module, and calling

`Thread(target=mouseCollect).start()`

You only have to do this once, you could probably even do it in the main body of the program

Comment: nice. this kinda helped. when it was a skript without gui i made it threaded (with the help of the nice people in stackoverflow^^), but i thought it would break somehow the gui thread. so i left it out. as i said it kinda worked: its not freezing now just saying: "QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. I somehow never realized, that you HAVE to use numpy arrays. also i didnt use curve.setdata for plotting.

the more or less final code(not full code) now looks like this:

```
class mouseCollect(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):

      QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run (self):
      global e, curve, curve2, data1, data2  
      while e.wait():
        tmp = getMouseEvent() #returns tuples in form of  (x,y)
        data1 = np.append(data1, tmp[0] )
        data2 = np.append(data2, tmp[1] )  
        sum1= np.cumsum(data1)
        sum2= np.cumsum(data2)     

        curve.setData(y=sum1)
        curve2.setData(y=sum2)
        guiPE # process event thingy

    def stop(self):
      e.clear()
```

well, it is a not really written efficiently, but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

The best approach for repetitive updates is to use a QTimer. In this way you allow program control to go back to the Qt event loop after every update (no infinite loops allowed), and Qt periodically invokes your update function for you.

For example, see one of the many the updating plot examples included with pyqtgraph: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/Plotting.py#L58

Threading is very difficult to do correctly and when it's done wrong you usually end up with crashing that is difficult to debug. I recommend to avoid threading until you are very confident with the event system and familiar with the pitfalls of threading.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I got now both versions running(threaded and timer). the timer version runs fine, but it freezes, when i try to use another input device to click buttons and such. so i think since the threded version has no problems at the moment i'll stick with that solution^^